# Elastic not syncyinh proper data from mysql

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to insert records from mysql to elastic. I am inserting two records only. 'prod_id' is primary key in mysql DB.

below is my insert query.

```
$elastic->setIndex("tbl_product");
    $elastic->setType("products");
    //$elastic->setConnection(new MySQLiConnection());
    //Where 1st param is the database connection and 2nd param is tableName
    $elastic->setSqlQuery("SELECT *
                  FROM tbl_product
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_product_details ON tbl_product.prod_id = tbl_product_details.prod_id
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_product_seo ON tbl_product.prod_id = tbl_product_seo.prod_id
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_product_keywords ON tbl_product.prod_id = tbl_product_keywords.prod_id
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_category.cat_id = tbl_product.cat_id
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_manufacturer ON tbl_manufacturer.manuf_id = tbl_product.manuf_id LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 18000");
    $elastic->insertAllData($connection);
```

/***** Below is elastic array after inserting *****/

Search Function:

```
   $params = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
            "from" => 0, "size" => 1000,
            //"scroll" => "1m",

            'body'  => [
            "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => $query
                          ]
                     ],
                     [
                          "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ];

    $query  = $client->search($params);


    //return  array($this->extractResult($query),$this->extractResult($query1));
    return  $this->extractResult($query);
```

Above function returns below array. For example I have shown only two fields in array.

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 16579
                [lang_id] => 1

            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 
                [lang_id] => 1

            )
```

In second 'prod_id' is null. Any idea why this is happening?

Below is my mapping.

```
'mappings' => [
                'article' => [
                    'properties' => [
                        'prod_id' => [
                            'type' => 'integer'
                        ],
                        'lang_id' => [
                            'type' => 'string'
                        ],
              ]
           ]
        ]
```

Comment: `In second 'prod_id' is null. Any idea why this is happening?`=> how can we say? we don't know how you are creating that array and how's your are trying to insert them (because no code is shared).

Comment: share inserting code

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have edited my post. I forgot to put insert query.

Comment: @rahulmr I have inserted code